# Bash on Windows has no command history

Tags: windows-10, bash

When I am starting the bash console on Windows 10, I can't access the last command by pressing the arrow-up button on my keyboard.

I don't know why, but on my laptop this does work.

How can I make it work on this machine, too?

Comment: What happens if you run the `history` command?

Comment: It prints `1  history`

Comment: And if you now press the up arrow nothing happens?

Comment: @DavidPostill I just tried it again and now it works, interestingly. This `history` command might have changed something. Do you know what happened?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of WSL?

Comment: The up arrow will only work if you have previous commands in your history.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and my own experience, the first time you enter the 'history' command  appears to enable the shell history feature.